# : Why does App\Event' not found? when passing its routes

Tags: laravel

C:\xampp\htdocs\jsapp\app\Http\Controllers\EventsController.php:17

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Event;

class EventsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function index()
    {
        $events=Event::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(5);
        return view('events.index')->with('events', $events);
    }
```

Comment: Does the file exist? What's its namespace? What version of Laravel? (Should that maybe be `App\Models\Event`?)

Answer (score 1):

What version of your laravel? If it is greater than version 7, the model namespace has been changed to:

```php
use App\Models\ModelName;
```

Also check the model file if the namespace is exactly what you are passing, except the class name:

```php
namespace App;
```

In the new versions of laravel, as a folder called Models has been integrated into the app directory, models have the namespace:

```php
namespace App\Models;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the namespace for Event model